# Properties inside method showing undefined but working outside the methods . How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

In the below code when I do console.log(teacher1.getDetails()); the property value shows undefined but when I do console.log(teacher1.personName) or console.log(teacher.mainSubject) it shows property value. What is happening here? What am I missing? Can somebody explain it please? And how to make it work?

```js
let Person = function(personName, age) {
  this.personName = personName;
  this.age = age;
};

Person.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `Person Name:${this.personName}. Age is ${this.age}.`;
};

//Child constructor function
let Teacher = function(personName, age, mainSubject) {
  Person.call(this, personName, age);
  this.mainSubject = mainSubject;
};
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); //inheritance
Teacher.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `${this.__proto__.getDetails()} Main subject is ${this.mainSubject}.`; //optionally invoke the parent method.
};

let teacher1 = new Teacher("Sakib", 35, "Physics");
console.log(teacher1.getDetails()); //invokes Teacher.getDetails() method (child's method).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems in your code:

- `this.__proto__.getDetails()` doesn't directly calls the `getDetails` function defined in `Person.prototype` because in the first invocation of `getDetails()` function, `this.__proto__` returns `Teacher.prototype`. As a result, `this.__proto__.getDetails()` invokes itself, i.e. `Teacher.prototype.getDetails()`

  When `Teacher.prototype.getDetails()` is called for the second time, `this.__proto__` now refers to `Person.prototype` because `this` is now `Teacher.prototype` and its prototype is `Person.prototype`.

  The second call to `Teacher.prototype.getDetails()` invokes the `Person.prototype.getDetails()` function
- You need to bind `this` to make sure that value of `this` inside `Person.prototype.getDetails()` is correct
- You shouldn't use `__proto__` - its deprecated. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` to get a prototype of an object

Fixed Code:

```js
let Person = function(personName, age) {
  this.personName = personName;
  this.age = age;
};

Person.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `Person Name:${this.personName}. Age is ${this.age}.`;
};

let Teacher = function(personName, age, mainSubject) {
  Person.call(this, personName, age);
  this.mainSubject = mainSubject;
};

Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Teacher.prototype.constructor = Teacher;

Teacher.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  const personPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
  return `${personPrototype.getDetails.call(this)} Main subject is ${this.mainSubject}.`;
};

let teacher1 = new Teacher("Sakib", 35, "Physics");
console.log(teacher1.getDetails());
```

Comment: I learned the code from a tutorial where the properties of both parent and child constructor function were predefined . I tried to make it dynamic and supply the property value as arguments/parameters . That code from tutorial worked but mine not. The way you explained, it was very helpful for me. Thank you so so much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement getDetails method in the Teacher class like this:

```js
Teacher.prototype.getDetails = function() {
    return `${Person.prototype.getDetails.call(this)} Main subject is ${this.mainSubject}.`;
}
```

Your implementation doesn't work because of next: you call the parent method regarding parent's context which doesn't have values defined because in Teacher constructor you define values regarding the child context.

```js
Person.call(this, personName, age);
```

**Working example:**

```js
let Person = function(personName, age) {
  this.personName = personName;
  this.age = age;
};

Person.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `Person Name:${this.personName}. Age is ${this.age}.`;
};

//Child constructor function
let Teacher = function(personName, age, mainSubject) {
  Person.call(this, personName, age);
  this.mainSubject = mainSubject;
};
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); //inheritance
Teacher.prototype.getDetails = function() {
  return `${Person.prototype.getDetails.call(this)} Main subject is ${this.mainSubject}.`; //optionally invoke the parent method.
};

let teacher1 = new Teacher("Sakib", 35, "Physics");
console.log(teacher1.getDetails()); //invokes Teacher.getDetails() method (child's method).
```

Comment: Thanks . This worked . But I still don't know how it's working. Can you refer me some reading materials on this? It'd be very kind of you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).